# How to get InputStreamReader in ISO-8859-15?

Tags: java, character-encoding, bufferedreader, iso, inputstreamreader

How can I make this inputstream read a ISO-8859-15 encoded file?

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jet)));
```

I found this line which seemingly works:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ftp.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-15"));
```

But

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jet), "ISO-8859-15"));
```

does not.

Comment: If the 2nd one works then....

Comment: The second one is an InputStreamReader for FTP, rather than a raw resource.

Comment: Irrelevant. The point is that it specifies the charset, not where its input is coming from.

Comment: I dont understand why sending a String works in one case while in the other one needs to send a Charset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jet), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15")));
```

works. Apparently you need to send a Charset, not a String with the encoding in this case. Given this it seems strange that this works then:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ftp.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-15"));
```